# web3js: Can I send a signed Transaction without wait the result?

Tags: web3js, sendsignedtransaction

Commonly, I dow

```
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(web3, signed_transaction);
console.log("tx_hash:", receipt.transactionHash);
console.log("gas_used:", receipt.gasUsed);
console.log("gas_price:", offered_gas_price);
```

But I do not want  (no more) to get the return output, because it's too slow.

So I started a nodejs server to listen to contract events, and it works.

No, how can I call `web3.eth.ssendSignedTransaction` without wait for result?

I simply tried to call

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(web3, signed_transaction);
```

But I discovered that nothing is happening at all against my contract.

Should be a js problem only. 
But, in case no, can I simply send a transaction and ignore esit?

how?

Comment: You should be able to send a transaction without waiting for confirmations. I'd check if the transaction status, if it is in the pending pool, or it was mined and it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to send a transaction without waiting for confirmations. I'd check if the transaction status, if it is in the pending pool, or it was mined and it failed.

With web3 1.2 you can listen for the `transactionHash` and query for the transaction details. See the documentation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/callbacks-promises-events.html#promievent

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x...')
  .once('transactionHash', function(hash){
    web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).then(() => {
    ..
  })
})
```

---

To wait for the hash you might wrap the call in a promise

```
function waitForHash(signedTx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx)
      .once('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        resolve(hash)
    })
  })
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
const hash = await waitForHash('0x....')
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can we stop js just untile the once is executed? using await it waits for then, and it's too long to leave js pending in my specific case. How can I wait only for this event?

Comment: @realtebo I edited my question to show one possible method to wait for hash. I don't know if it will work in your case because you need to wait until the transaction has been sent.

Comment: Thanks again. I ended just waiting for the hash, and the a parallele job query contract events to get results. You mada me discovere the `PromiEvent` I didn't know before.